# Why function parameters doesn't work with class

Tags: php, wordpress

I created a class. The code is below

```
class Another {

    public $error = array();

    public function set_error( $key, $value )
    {
        if ( isset( $key ) ) {
            $sanitizedKey = sanitize_key( $key );

            $this->error[ $sanitizedKey ] = wp_json_encode( $value );

            return $this->error;
        }
    }

    public function get_error( $id )
    {
        if ( ! is_null( $id ) ) {
            return $this->error[ $id ];
        }
    }

    public function print_error()
    {
        if ( $this->error ) {
            foreach ($this->error as $key => $value) {
                $decodeJson = json_decode( $value );
                ?>
                <div class="ud-error">
                    <p class="ud-error-<?php echo $key; ?>">
                        <?php echo __( $decodeJson, 'ud-for-edd' ); ?>
                    </p>
                </div>
                <?php
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If I invoke it in the following way it works. It echos the content as expected.

```
$error = new Another();
$error->set_error('gg', 'hhhh');
$error->print_error();
```

But if I use it with function then it doesn't work as expected. Do I have to pass parameters by reference or any other? The following way it doesn't work

```
function create_error($id, $val) {
    $errr = new Another();
    return $errr->set_error($id, $val);
}

create_error('raa', 'raashid');

$error = new Another();
$error->print_error();
```

I am confused about why this doesn't work. Any clue. Thanks in advance.

**Steps I want the code to perform:**

1. Create a class with 3 methods, `set_error, get_error, and print_error`
2. Then invoke the class inside the function. The function will accept two parameters because inside the class the `set_error()` method accepts two parameters.
3. In order to print the error, I will instantiate the class and call the print_error() method.
4. In case, if I have to print the new error. I will just call the `create_error()` function to do this for me. Because the function needs 2 parameters. The arguments supplied to the function must be supplied as arguments to the set_error() method.

I hope the list helps.

**Update:**

If I use a global variable then it works. Below is working.

```
$customError = new Another();

function create_error($id, $val) {
    global $customError;
    $customError->set_error($id, $val);
}

create_error('raa', 'rashid');

$customError->print_error();
```

Thanks, @roggsFolly and @El_Vanja. By understanding your tips I was able to solve the error. If there is anything wrong with the code I just said worked. Please point out.

Comment: _it doesn't work as expected_ Not helpful. What does it do, whats wrong with what it does

Comment: You do I suppose realise that `create_error('raa', 'raashid');` does not accept the returned value therefore it is lost forever?

Comment: what is expected? In the 2nd example, it calls set_error on a different object than print_error, so I would expect nothing to print

Comment: Look at what you're doing: `return $errr->set_error($id, $val);` - you're not returning your class instance. You're returning whatever `set_error` returns (which is either an array or *nothing*).

Comment: Also the object you create in the function scope is not visible in the main scope

Comment: Thanks for your @RiggsFolly. If I create a function, then if I pass the value through the function to the class. Because the class method set_error() has two parameters. If I use it through a function way. It doesn't work.

Comment: But you create a NEW Another and then try and print an error from that. But you didnt set an error into that object

Comment: Will you please edit the code or add comments inside code so I can understand what you are trying to say.

Comment: Side note: `if ( ! is_null( $id ) ) { return $this->error[ $id ]; }` will likely give you "Undefined index"notices in the future. It's not sufficient to check if the key was provided, you should also check if it exists in the array.

Comment: Thanks, @El_Vanja. Noted the point

Comment: Point 4 in your edit isn't clear. Are you tring to say you want `create_error` to print the error without having to explicitly call `print_error`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The object you instantiate inside the function is not the same one you try and print the error message from.

First the object you instantiate inside the function scope is not visible outside the function.

```
function create_error($id, $val) {
    $errr = new Another();
    return $errr->set_error($id, $val);
}

create_error('raa', 'raashid');

// this instantiates a seperate Another object from the one
// you created in the function 
$error = new Another();
// this tries to print from the new object taht has no message stored in it yet
$error->print_error();
```

To instantiate the object inside a function scope and then use that object outside the function scope you must pass that object back to the caller of the function

```
function create_error($id, $val) {
    $errr = new Another();
    $errr->set_error($id, $val);
    return $errr;   // this returns the object
}

$error = create_error('raa', 'raashid');
// now you can use its methods to print the stored message
$error->print_error();
```

**Update as per your additional Information**

A couple of things I think you may be getting confused about.

1. Each time you do `$var = new ObjectName;` you are creating a brand new instance of that class. This new instance has no knowledge about any other instances of that class that may or may not have been created before or may be created after that point. And more specifically to your problems, it does not have access to the properties of another version of that object.
2. You are I believe missing the concept of [variable scope](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php). The Object you create inside that function, will only actually exist while the function is running. Once the function completes anything created/instantiated wholly within that function is **DESTROYED** ( well in truth it is just no longer accessible ) but to all intent and purpose it is destroyed. you therefore cannot expect to be able to address it outside the scope of the function.
3. If you want the Object you instantiate within the function to be usable outside the function, you must pass a reference to that object out of the function to the calling code. This passes that reference into the scope of the calling code and keeps the object alive, global scope in your case, but that might be another function or even another object. That allows you access to that instantiation and any properties that were set within it.

Comment: Didnt understood this part $error = =create_error('raa', 'raashid');

Comment: Sorry, that was my typo, fixed it

Comment: We have a problem. If you will please check the function code I provided. Inside the function I invoke set_error() method. The set_error() method accepts two parameters. ALso the create method doesn't exist inside code.

Comment: The basic idea is to pass parameters to the function which will, in turn, pass the arguments to the set_error() method.

Comment: Also, I don't want the print_error() method to be dependent on the function.

Comment: I dont quite understand what you mean by dependant

Comment: Ok. I will provide detail on what I mean to say

Comment: Does that additional info help you?

Comment: It was the issue of variable scoping. I know variable scoping but sometimes I forgot the basic concepts. Anyway, humans create errors. Anyway thanks